# android cannt use data function in query

Tags: android, sqlite

I cant get any result if i put "date('now', 'localtime')" in the query.

My original code is:

```
Cursor record = db.query(RECORD_TABLE, null, date(UTC_DATETIME,'localtime') = ? ",
            new String[]{"date('now', 'localtime')"},null,null,null);
```

It doesn't return any result.

But I can get result if I use:

```
Cursor record = db.query(RECORD_TABLE,null, date(UTC_DATETIME,'localtime') = ? ",
            new String[]{"2014-05-13"},null,null,null);
```

Is there a way that I can use "date('now', 'localtime')" in my query?

Comment: You can do that... but not like that - Please, refer to this page: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
change your code new String[]{ dateFormat.format(date)}

Comment: this does not actually compile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of parameters is to prevent their values from being interpreted as SQL expressions.

To call an SQL function, you have to put it into the SQL string:

```
Cursor record = db.query(RECORD_TABLE, null,
        "date(UTC_DATETIME,'localtime') = date('now', 'localtime')",
        null,null,null,null);
```

Please note that the `localtime` conversion affects both values in the same way, so you can omit it:

```
Cursor record = db.query(RECORD_TABLE, null,
        "date(UTC_DATETIME) = date('now')",
        null,null,null,null);
```

or even omit the first `date` call if the `UTC_DATETIME` column alread is in the correct `yyyy-MM-dd` format:

```
Cursor record = db.query(RECORD_TABLE, null,
        "UTC_DATETIME = date('now')",
        null,null,null,null);
```